# How do I add effects to list items when a page is opened?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am attempting to add some flare to an amateur photography website. I would like to put an effect on the list items on the page that lists my albums (e.g. Norway, Iceland, Germany etc.) See below for my navigation:

```
<nav id="navigation">
    <div class="logo">
        <h4>Christian Townsend</h4>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav-links">
        <li class="nav-links-active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li class="photography"><a href="work.html">Photography</a></li>
        <li class="albums-header"><a href="projects.html">Projects</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="burger">
        <div class="line1"></div>
        <div class="line2"></div>
        <div class="line3"></div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

When a user clicks on the `Photography` list item, I would like to put an effect on the list items on work.html

```
<div class="albums">

    <h2>Albums</h2>

    <ul class="album-animation" style="list-style-type:none;">
        <li><a href="norway.html">Norway</a></li>
        <li>Iceland</li>
        <li>Holland</li>
        <li>Germany</li>
        <li>Italy</li>
        <li>Austria</li>
        <li>Spain</li>
        <li>Czech Republic</li>
        <li>France</li>
        <li>England</li>
        <li>Wales</li>
        <li>Scotland</li>
        <li>Ireland</li>
        <li>Australia</li>
    </ul>

</div>
```

I have the below JavaScript code but it isn't having any effect on my list items

```
const photography = document.querySelector('.photography');
const albumLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.album-animation li');

photography.addEventListener('click', () => {
    // Animate links

    albumLinks.forEach((link, index) => {
        if (link.style.animation) {
            link.style.animation = '';

        } else {
            link.style.animation = `navLinkFade 0.5s ease forwards ${index / 10 + 0.9}s`;
        }
    });

});
```

The CSS

```
@keyframes navLinkFade { 
    from { opacity: 0; transform: translateX(50px); } 
    to { opacity: 1; transform: translateX(0px) }
}
```

Comment: In your JS, you used `navLinkFade`. I think that's in your CSS. Mind showing us the relevant CSS?

Comment: `@keyframes navLinkFade {
    from {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translateX(50px);
    }

    to {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translateX(0px)
    }
}`

Comment: Are the two elements (`nav#navigation` and `div.albums`) on the same HTML page?

Comment: how did you link your script file? your photography class and album-animation classes are on a different file, so when you try to use the script file linked, it may give you errors because it won't be able to find the other class. if everything is in single file it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you just need to add the CSS animation on page load. Run code snippet to see what happens on page load.

```js
const albumLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.album-animation li');

window.onload = (event) => {
  albumLinks.forEach((link, index) => {
      if (link.style.animation) {
          link.style.animation = '';

      } else {
          link.style.animation = `navLinkFade 0.5s ease forwards ${index / 10 + 0.9}s`;
      }
  });
};
```

```css
@keyframes navLinkFade { 
    from { opacity: 0; transform: translateX(50px); } 
    to { opacity: 1; transform: translateX(0px) }
}
```

```html
<div class="albums">

    <h2>Albums</h2>

    <ul class="album-animation" style="list-style-type:none;">
        <li><a href="norway.html">Norway</a></li>
        <li>Iceland</li>
        <li>Holland</li>
        <li>Germany</li>
        <li>Italy</li>
        <li>Austria</li>
        <li>Spain</li>
        <li>Czech Republic</li>
        <li>France</li>
        <li>England</li>
        <li>Wales</li>
        <li>Scotland</li>
        <li>Ireland</li>
        <li>Australia</li>
    </ul>

</div>
```

Comment: This is essentially what I want except I want all of the items to be invisible and for the effect to reveal each of the items one at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, Geetanjali. Your solution was perfect. I just needed to change the innate opacity of the list items to 0 and now the effects work as desired.